# C++: Does the Null get stored when storing a char array in a textfile?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, fstream, ofstream

Have a look at this code

```
ofstream obj("output.txt");
obj<<"Hello World";
```

Here i send to the text file "output.txt" The char array "Hello World"

Now char arrays are have a terminating null at the end of them.

So when i send the char array  to the text file "output.txt", Does the terminating null get sent and stored as well or not and why?

Comment: You could easily inspect this with a hex editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider what would happen if you wrote several times to the file:

```
ofstream output("myfile.txt");
output << "Hello";
output << " ";
output << "world";
```

If the string terminator was added each time you write something to the file, when you write the second time the system would then have to find the zero in the file, remove it, and then add it again after the new text. Also, the system would have to be implemented differently for output to e.g. the console.

So to answer your question: No, the terminator is not written. It's only used by strings in memory for functions to know where the strings end in memory.

Comment: To add, if you use the output.write(), then depending on how you call it, the null can be written if you want it.

Comment: @RobertMason If the strings aren't literals, but `std::string`, they can also contain nul characters.

Comment: @RobertMason Of course, but then it's _you_ who decide to write it and not the underlying system.

Answer (score 2):

No. The null termination is just what C/C++ uses to know where the string ends.

Note that it would be a pretty annoying loss of control to have it write a 0x00 byte after the characters you really want. Then, to just write the characters you want would be a bit of a hassle.

Comment: If by "C/C++" you mean "functions that deal with zero-terminated strings".

Comment: @MikeSeymour I guess I meant that this is how the C standard defines a string, although you're certainly right that it's only relevant for functions that deal with them. And in C++, that's not going to be as common as it is in C.